# Json inside App Phonegap ! What is the Path?

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova, phonegap-build

I have some issue about my Phonegap App!

When I test inside my browser all works Well !
But when I compile to apk... In my phone doesn't find the JSON...
I'm new in programming , sorry about my bad english too...

What Can I do ?

```
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 23);

$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: "/../pages/desafio/desafiando.json",
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json',
crossDomain: true,
cache:false,
success: function(data) 
{
    $.each(data, function(i, desafio) {
        item = "<center><h4>" + desafio.meta + "</h4></center>";

        if (desafio.id == number) {
            $('#blocodesafio').append(item);
        }
    });
},
error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert('Erro ao carregar');
    console.log(errorThrown);
}
```

I'm thinking " /../pages/desafio/desafiando.json " this is the problem but I don't know what I have to put to work inside phonegap...

Comment: Maybe I can't do it... Someone Know about it ?

Comment: Where is that location on your computer? You need it to be in the app directory. I put mine in a /json folder that is at the same level as my /js and my /css folder.

Comment: The directory /page is in the same level as /js /cs... Is this necessary ? For now I build a REST to get my JSON... But I want to do my app a offline app...

Comment: It's not necessary but what you are describing suggests that the problem is your url path.

Comment: @JhonatanMark did you solve this problem? I am having the same issue. I had my json file next to my `index.html` file.  What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "You need it to be in the app directory. I put mine in a /json folder that is at the same level as my /js and my /css folder." - Subjective Effect

I Put My JSON in a REST WS ... And worked...

But after the review, I was curious about whether the folder level would make a difference, and redid the application, placing the JSON in the same level of / JS / CSS ...
And REALLY WORKED.